# How can I draw curves above a mesh surface?

Tags: opengl, shaders, graphic-effects

I am making an animation of a deformed sphere that represents some aspects of the wave function in a hydrogen atom.  I am starting with an octahedron that i push through a tessellation shader. The tessellation evaluation shader then first deforms the octahedron into something more sphere-like and then applies the deformation stuff.

Now, to further improve the visual impression of the deformation, I would like to place lines on top of the sphere and also deform those, to achieve something resembling level curves.  What would be a good way to achieve this? Generating circles on the cpu side and then sending them to GL and having them deformed separately seems rather odd, but I cannot figure out another way.

If I want to achieve this in one shader run I am also limited to drawing triangles (patches) and making these appear as lines also seems rather unwieldy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than using a geometry shader as mentioned in another answer, I managed to implement the lines very cleanly in the fragment shader, by passing the spherical coordinates before the deformation from the tessellation shader to the fragment shader. There I could then use uniforms that describe the number of level curves to calculate position and line width etc. which then can be transformed to colour...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a geometry shader to generate those lines.

There are a few tutorials/examples on how to generate sprites with geometry shaders, you can base yourself off of these to create thick lines with triangle strips from line strips.

http://www.geeks3d.com/20140815/particle-billboarding-with-the-geometry-shader-glsl/